# Restrict the size of disk space of each user - tljh and ldapauthentificator

Tags: linux, ldap, jupyterhub

We have set up a jupyterhub Server (the littest jupyter hub) with an LDAP Authentification on our own server.
You can limit the memory and cpu that can be used by each individual user via the config and the commands looks like

```
sudo tljh-config set limits.memory 4G
sudo tljh-config set limits.cpu 2
```

But there is no similar way to set a limit for the disk space, that means the home directory for each new user.

It is possible to use "mkhomedir_helper" called in the configuration of the LDAPAuthenticator:

```
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'ldapauthenticator.LDAPAuthenticator'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.server_hosts = ['ldaps://ldap1.example.com:636', 'ldaps://ldap2.example.com:636']
c.LDAPAuthenticator.bind_user_dn = 'uid=imauser,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.bind_user_password = 'imapassword'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.user_search_base = 'ou=People,dc=example,dc=com'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.user_search_filter = '(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid={username}))'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.username_pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9_.][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{0,252}[a-zA-Z0-9_.$-]?'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.create_user_home_dir = True
c.LDAPAuthenticator.create_user_home_dir_cmd = ['mkhomedir_helper']
```

Is it possible to use a script that includes commands like *quota ...*., instead of "mkhomedir_helper" ?

We created a file that is placed in the same directory as mkhomedir_helper.
It includes only for test purposes

```
#!bin/bash
  mkdir /tmp/testdir
```

We expect that during the login of a new user this script with this command is executed.

But: a new user logged in and a home directory is created but the command in the mentioned file was not executed. The log gave no clues.